# How to use GridBagConstraints in a JPanel class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, panel

I am trying to use the gridbagconstraints in a class that extends JPanel but after putting that codes like ths :

```
    import java.awt.Insets;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;

    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class RightPanel extends JPanel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

JLabel start;
JLabel first;

GridBagConstraints c;

public RightPanel() {

    setVisible(true);

    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.insets = new Insets(10 ,10, 10, 10);

    start = new JLabel("Start");
    start.setFont(new Font("comic sans ms", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    start.setForeground (new Color(111,0,0));

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 5;

    add(start, c);

    first = new JLabel("About");
    first.setFont(new Font("comic sans ms", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    first.setForeground (new Color(111,0,0));

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 5;
    add(first ,c);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Image a = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\Favour's Computer\\workspace\\Physics Calculator\\src\\res\\rightside.PNG");
    g.drawImage(a, 0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height, this);
    super.paint(g);
}

    }
```

Now the problem is where to add the declaration code in the jpanel constucter i.e RightPanel rp = new RightPanel(new GridBagLayout());, but the new GridBagLayout() dosent work, please help

Comment: Can you possibly clarify your question? What "*doesn't work*" actually mean? Are you getting any errors/exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RightPanel rp = new RightPanel(new GridBagLayout());
```

The code above will not work because you don't have any parameter in your constructor..

```
public class RightPanel extends JPanel

//codes...

public RightPanel() //You don't have any parameter in your constructor
```

If you are trying to set the Layout of your class use

```
setLayout(new GridBagLayout())
```

Comment: thank ben like am a rookie and you just made this rookie happy

Comment: You can click the check to set this answer to your accepted answer :) Haha